# Can a familiar deliver only a portion of a touch spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, spellcasting, spell-components, touch-attacks

Can I have my familiar deliver only a portion of a touch spell and the caster deliver the other portion of it. The specific spell in question is [Fly](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fly) (upcast to 5th level because Warlock) and my character is in touch distance of one of the targets while my familiar is within touch distance of two others. But my character is not within touch distance of the other two and the familiar isn't in touch distance of the other one.

So my question is: "Can my familiar deliver the spell to two of the targets while I deliver it to the third?"

The DM has made the temporary ruling for now that it can't but he has also been shown to be willing to change rulings like this after receiving an answer here.